# Change another word on condition of a word in the same row in command line?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I got a `html` file which is as follows(delete some unuseful words).

```
<li class="toctree-l1">examples</a></li>
<li class="toctree-l3">charcnn</a></li>
<li class="toctree-l4">cifar10</a></li>
```

What I want is to edit it without going into the file (`sed` command for example). I had a `dict` which is

```
dict = {'example':l1, 'charcnn':l2, 'cifar10':l3}
```

Following the `dict`, the `html` file should be

```
<li class="toctree-l1">examples</a></li>
<li class="toctree-l2">charcnn</a></li>
<li class="toctree-l3">cifar10</a></li>
```

Before the replacement it is `l1`, `l3` and `l4`. After it is `l1`, `l2` and `l3`.

I know the `sed` command can replace by key words, but it is used to replace the current words. Is there a way to replace another word on condition of a word in the same row?

Comment: The data is the same before and after. What is there to change?

Comment: @RamanSailopal Before is l1, l3 and l4. After is l1, l2 and l3.

Comment: Awk is a possibility for this but it isn't ideal for html/XML. We would need all the complete html file though.

Comment: `html/XML` is not the point. You can condiser it as other type of  file(`txt` for example). The core is whether we can replace another word on condition of a word in the same row.

Comment: I don't understand the sentence "What I want is to edit it without going into the file (sed command for example)." Can you rephrase or explain it, especially the phrase **"edit it without going into the file"**?

Comment: @Bodo Like `vim` operation, we go into the file.  `sed` do not.

Comment: You mean that you don't want to modify the original file but print the output or write it into a different file?

Comment: Sorry for my poor English. What I want to express is if we `vim` a file, we first need to comes into the file then we edit it. But for `sed`, we dont need to come into the file.

Comment: For me the difference between `vim` and `sed` is that `vim` is an interactive editor while `sed` is a (non-interactive) command line tool. Please clarify: Do you want to modify the original file or do you want to get a modified copy?

Comment: @Bodo modify the original file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course `sed` can replace one part of a string depending on a different part of the string.

For your example data you could use

```
sed 's#\(<li class="toctree-\)[^"]*\(">examples</a></li>\)#\1l1\2#
     s#\(<li class="toctree-\)[^"]*\(">charcnn</a></li>\)#\1l2\2#
     s#\(<li class="toctree-\)[^"]*\(">cifar10</a></li>\)#\1l3\2#' inputfile
```

The commands check the whole input string but allows anything between `toctree-` and `"`.

With this (modified) input

```
<li class="toctree-l1">examples</a></li>
<li class="toctree-l3">charcnn</a></li>
<li class="toctree-l4">cifar10</a></li>
<li class="toctree-something">other</a></li>
<li class="toctree-foo">examples</a></li>
<li class="toctree-bar">charcnn</a></li>
<li class="toctree-baz">cifar10</a></li>
```

the output is

```
<li class="toctree-l1">examples</a></li>
<li class="toctree-l2">charcnn</a></li>
<li class="toctree-l3">cifar10</a></li>
<li class="toctree-something">other</a></li>
<li class="toctree-l1">examples</a></li>
<li class="toctree-l2">charcnn</a></li>
<li class="toctree-l3">cifar10</a></li>
```

If you have the parameters for the replacement in a dictionary (`dict`), you could write some code that generates the `sed` commands from your dictionary in the form
`s#\(<li class="toctree-\)[^"]*\(">` *`key`* `</a></li>\)#\1` *`value`* `\2#`

Depending on your needs you can use different or shorter patterns like

```
s#\("toctree-\)[^"]*\(">examples<\)#\1l1\2#
```

**Edit** after clarification of the question in a comment:

To modify the original file you can either save the `sed` output in a new file and on success rename it to the original file name, e.g.

```
sed -e 'sed-command' inputfile > outputfile && mv outputfile inputfile
```

or use the `-i` option (in-place editing) if available

```
sed -i -e 'sed-command' inputfile
```

(Note that you may lose the original input in case your command contains an error.)

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v dict="{'example':l1, 'charcnn':l2, 'cifar10':l3}" '

       BEGIN{ 
                dict1=gensub(/[\}\{'"'"' ]/,"","g",dict);
                split(dict1,map,",") } 
       /toctree/ {
                cnt++;
                split(map[cnt],map1,":");
                print "<li class=\"toctree-"map1[2]"\">"map1[1]"</a></li>" }
            ' htmlfile
```

One liner:

```
awk -v dict="{'example':l1, 'charcnn':l2, 'cifar10':l3}" 'BEGIN{ dict1=gensub(/[\}\{'"'"' ]/,"","g",dict);split(dict1,map,",") } /toctree/ {cnt++;split(map[cnt],map1,":");print "<li class=\"toctree-"map1[2]"\">"map1[1]"</a></li>" }' htmlfile
```

Assuming "toctree" exists nowhere else in the htmlfile, you can try the above. First pass the dict in as variable to awk and then in the begin block, strip out the unnecessary characters and use the split function to place the entries in an array called map. We then search for any lines with toctree, increment a counter cnt, split the map array entry further into map1 using ":" as the delimiter and print the formatted strings as required.

The print no doubt will need working to ensure correct indentation.

Comment: I suggest to explain your `awk` code. My understanding is that it will not check the keywords `example`, `charcnn`... but processes the dictionary in order regardless of the number and order of matching input lines.

Comment: Yeah, that what I understood as the requirement. The order of the list will be dependent on the order of the entries in dict

Comment: I suggest to explain this in your answer. The question is not really clear about the requirements. From the name `dict` I assumed it to be meant as a dictionary which does not necessarily have a defined order.